# sum last n days quantity using sql window function

Tags: sql, subquery, date-arithmetic, alteryx, exasol

I am trying to create following logic in Alteryx and data is coming from Exasol database.

Column “Sum_Qty_28_days“ should sum up the values of “Qty ” column for same article which falls under last 28 days.

My sample data looks like:

[image]

and I want following output:

[image]

E.g. “Sum_Qty_28_days” value for “article” = ‘A’ and date = ‘’2019-10-8” is 8 because it is summing up the “Qty” values associated with dates (coming within previous 28 days) Which are:
2019-09-15
2019-10-05
2019-10-08
for “article” = ‘A’.

Is this possible using SQL window function?
I tried myself with following code:

```
SUM("Qty") OVER (PARTITION BY "article", date_trunc('month',"Date")
             ORDER BY "Date")
```

But, it is far from what I need. It is summing up the Qty for dates falling in same month. However, I need to sum of Qty for last 28 days.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Data is coming from Exasol RDBMS

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible using standard SQL and in many databases.  However, this will not work in all databases:

```
select t.*,
       sum(qty) over (partition by article
                      order by date
                      range between interval '27 day' preceding and current row
                     ) as sum_qty_28_days
from t;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the solution. My data is coming from Exasol database, and I am using Alteryx Designer to implement the logic. When I am trying with your solution it is giving me error "Error: Formula In-DB (5): Error SQLPrepare: [EXASOL][EXASolution driver]syntax error, unexpected PRECEDING_ [line 3, column 33] (Session: 1652450532585726518)"

Answer (score 1):

If your RDBMS does not support the `range` frame, an alternative solution is to use an inline subquery:

```
select 
    t.*,
    (
        select sum(t1.qty) 
        from mytable t1 
        where 
            t1.article = t.article
            and t1.date between t.date - interval 28 days and t.date
    ) sum_qty_28_days
from mytable t
```

Comment: Shouldn't date in-between range be referenced to  "t" table instead of "t1"?