# Combination of window function with datetime

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

#### Combination of window function with datetime:

Is there is something like this in Snowflake?:

```
select t.*,
       sum(qty) over (partition by article
                      order by date
                      range between interval '27 day' preceding and current row
                     ) as sum_qty_28_days
from t;
```

taken from:

[sum last n days quantity using sql window function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59249373/sum-last-n-days-quantity-using-sql-window-function)

Comment: have you found the answer for this question?

Answer (score 2):

From Snowflake's [**documentation**](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html#window-frame-syntax-and-usage)

> For sliding window frames:
>
> ROWS is inclusive and is always relative to the current row.
>
> **RANGE is not supported**.

Your best bet is a correlated subquery approach used in the link you shared.

Answer (score -1):

In snowflake, you can use the following query

```
select t.*,
       sum(qty) over (partition by article
                      order by date
                      rows between 27 preceding and current row
                     ) as sum_qty_28_days
from t;
```

Comment: Absolutely. But in case if one if the days is missing it might not be the most appropriate solution.